# Using Python+Theano with OpenCL in an AMD GPU

Tags: python, opencl, theano

I'm trying to use Python with Theano to accelerate some code with OpenCL. I installed `libgpuarray` and `pygpu` as instructed (I think), and got no errors. The installation detected the OpenCL runtime installed.

I just cannot run the Theano example for OpenCL, mainly because I don't know how to specify my GPU. My GPU is a `Radeon HD 5340/5450/5470`, according to `inxi`. All code in the Theano documentation uses `device=cuda0` and the only place where OpenCL is mentioned, it says `device=openclN` where `N` is a number.

I tried `device=opencl0` and got a `pygpu` error saying that the correct format is `opencl<int>:<int>`. I have since tried any number of combinations of numbers (`opencl0:0` and such), and always an `GpuArrayException: Unknown error`.

My system is Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and my hardware is a Toshiba Satellite, 15". I installed `Theano` with `pip`, and later installed `libgpuarray` following the instructions on their site.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the OS and compiler you're using?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 and for compiler, I don't know, I'm directly using `Theano` from Python. I suppose it should select the right compiler?

Comment: How was Theano compiled? How was PyGPU compiled? How did you install them on your machine?

Comment: I installed `theano` with `pip` from a downloaded `tar.gz`, and `pygpu` by downloading and compiling `libgpuarray` manually.

Comment: Which compiler did you use to do that? When dealing with low-level stuff like this, you'd typically need the details of the compiler, OS, and CPU (GPU) as a prerequisite for any help.

Comment: I really just downloaded `libgpuarray` and executed `make`, `make install`, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68926/discussion-between-alejandro-piad-and-noob-saibot).

Comment: I really don't have anything more for you. Just trying to get you to put out more info for someone else who stumbles on this. From what I could *guess*, your compiler is GCC-something, on a "mobile version" of Ubuntu, with an AMD processor, and no GPU. See what I mean? Edit your question with the correct details.

Comment: I get the same exact error.  I am using Intel HD4000 with the beignet 1.0.1 (openCL) drivers. Installed Theano from archlinux aur, installed clBLAS via source, installed libgpuarray via source.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

opencl0:0 is correct.  Could you confirm that pyopencl works?  You may have a problem with your opencl (or drivers/cl compiler).

However, I think Theano does not quite work with OpenCL at the moment.  The current state is there is partial support, enough for "hello world", but not enough to run any significant code.

See:

https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/2189

https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/1471

https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/2190

https://github.com/Theano/Theano/pull/1732

To summarize, no, most stuff is not ported (including Elemwise, for example, which is a common op).  I would really like to see Theano on OpenCL though.  That would be a great thing for AMD to pitch in on.  Soon :)

Comment: If that is the case, then there is no point in trying further until more sutff has been ported. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: The latest version of Theano and pyopencl works fine with my AMD Radeon HD 7750 cards with the latest catalyst, libgpuarray installed in Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

Comment: Tried Theano+OpenCL and discovered that lasagne will not cooperate with OpenCL at this point in time.