# OpenCL / AMD: Deep Learning

Tags: sdk, opencl, neural-network, gpgpu, deep-learning

While "googl'ing" and doing some research I were not able to find **any** serious/popular framework/sdk for scientific GPGPU-Computing and *OpenCL* on *AMD* hardware. Is there any literature and/or software I missed?

Especially I am interested in **deep learning**.

For all I know *deeplearning.net* recommends *NVIDIA* hardware and *CUDA* frameworks. Additionally all big deep learning frameworks I know, such as *Caffe*, *Theano*, *Torch*, *DL4J*, ... are focussed on *CUDA* and do not plan to support *OpenCL/AMD*.

Furthermore one can find plenty of scientific papers as well as corresponding literature for *CUDA* based deep learning tasks but nearly nothing for *OpenCL/AMD* based solutions.

Is there any chance that new or existing scientific frameworks will show up for *OpenCL/AMD* based solutions in 2015/16?

What is a good start for *deep learning* with *OpenCL/AMD*? Any literature? Tutorials? Miscellaneous sources?

Comment: There are reasons, why deep learning frameworks use CUDA instead of OpenCL - one of them is performance. It's easier to tune it for single vendor like Nvidia. Though I don't know exact answer, there are little chances to find that kind of software for AMD.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is, more or less, what I expected and found out so far. As I already mentioned, even Google has not supplied many results :( Is there really no official source, no literature, no tutorials, no attempts out there?

Comment: Theano seems to have some sort of OpenCL support available, via `GpuArray`: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html#gpuarray

Comment: See also the [Comparison of deep learning software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_deep_learning_software) Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Edit 1** See [Mikael Rousson's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32690414/4013571) answer - Amazon is now the way forwards as you can "rent" computational power from them.

**Edit 2** I've created a [series of guides](https://flipdazed.github.io/blog/deep%20learning/set-up-amazon-ec2) on how to set up Amazon EC2 Instances for Deep Learning with `theano`. It's a *lot more* convenient than running on a personal machine.

**Edit 3** It seems that TensorFlow is now far more widely accepted than `theano` so I have updated the guide accordingly.

I have been in the same situation as yourself as I have a MacBook Pro with Intel Iris graphics. I have spent the best part of a week looking through all possible workarounds and I would be more than welcome to alternatives to those that I offer.

The best solution I currently have is to:

1. Install the `python` library [`tensorflow`](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/) and utilise what GPU support there is and continue to update to the latest development versions.
2. Use [`theano`](http://theano.readthedocs.org) - and use [existing GPU support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28749022/4013571) similarly to `tensorflow`
3. Buy an NVIDIA graphics card and use it on a PC
4. If you absolutely need a solution in OpenCL and you are willing to code everything from a high level of understanding (no tutorials) look at [DeepCL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DeepCL/5.10.2) and possibly [pyOpenCl](http://mathema.tician.de/software/pyopencl/).

I have found that any solution using OpenCL, e.g. [pyOpenCl](http://mathema.tician.de/software/pyopencl/), doesn't yet have user friendly interfaces for Deep Learning i.e. it will take longer to code it in an alternative method than to just code it fast and run on a CPU. With that said though, here are of the best alternative OpenCL libraries for deep learning:

- [Python - DeepCL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DeepCL/5.10.2)
- [Jonathan's Torch7 Utility Library - C++](https://github.com/jonathantompson/jtorch)

*In Development*

- [`tensorflow`](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/) is [adding](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22) OpenCL support once improvements to `Eigen` and other dependencies are [finished](https://www.codeplay.com/portal/05-22-17-implementing-opencl-support-for-eigen-using-sycl-and-computecpp)
- [`theano`](http://theano.readthedocs.org) is [adding support](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/1471) to OpenCL through [`clBLAS`](https://github.com/clMathLibraries/clBLAS)
- [`Caffe`](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org) is in [development stages](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/2195) of adding OpenCL support but a bit behind `theano` in progress, it seems

Comment: I appreciate your answer & upvoted it, thanks! However, I will wait some days with the bounty, maybe a more extensive answer arrives with more official sources or even scientific papers / literature about the topic.

Comment: I realised I didn't actually list the libraries that use OpenCL that I referred to in my original edit - updated this now. I also added a bit more information with regards to libraries in development stages. Likewise, I hope someone will provide an answer that solves all my OpenCL issues as I'm currently looking at trading my laptop up for an NVIDIA graphics version which will be effort & costly!

Comment: Thanks! I'm in the same situation. Desktop is AMD based, Notebook Intel based and NVIDIA hardware is not known for beeing cheap or having good price-performance ratios for GPU-Computing, especially when it comes to double precision operations :/

Comment: Update: Two claims that OpenCL works with Theano: [here](https://gist.github.com/jarutis/ff28bca8cfb9ce0c8b1a) and [here](http://tinyfool.org/2016/04/how-to-install-theano-opencl-on-mac-os-x-ei-caption/) I haven't checked as I'm heavy into my thesis project but leaving here in case someone else has time. The [official github issue](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/2936) states that OpenCL is *not currently usable* and the issue stack supports that

Comment: Update: Currently many libraries and framework support AMD hardware through their GPU open initiative. Cool things are happening there e.g. like cross platform code that runs both on AMD and Nvidia without any deep changes. check my answer in the link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33330306/2442649

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane,  Gr8 Reply. By any chance do u know any of these frameworks is compatible with OpenCL 1.1 EP?

Answer (score 17):

--- Aug 2017 Update cool new things happened in the AMD side ---

now it is actually possible to run any library on most AMD hardware 
[Check Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38773228/2442649)

As of 25 October 2015

it seems that AMD and others have extended their hands on the development of several OpenCL accelerated frameworks for deeplearning. So yeah OpenCL support is now existent for deeplearning :)

This is a list of OpenCL accelarated framework or tools that have been developed keeping deep learning in mind primarily. I hope they will get updated over the upcoming years

We know right now(25 October 2015) there are three deep learning framework that are very very popular to researchers and has seen some commercial products

1. Theano
2. Caffe
3. Torch

---

caffe has a pretty good OpenCL support because amd developed a complete version of caffe which supports almost all the features of caffe and also it is being developed actively. it is named OpenCL Caffe. and here is the repository

[OpenCL Caffe](https://github.com/amd/OpenCL-caffe)

if you are thinking about performance then according to that site(i have not bench-marked it myself) it gives around 261 images per second or 22.5 million images per day in a AMD R9 Fury hardware(training). to compare with nvidia K40, which can process 40 million images a day. so according to the site it can give half performance in one-sixth money.(considering k40 is 3000$ card and r9 fury is around 600$). however using any consumer card will give you a problem about memory(vram) which is quite important in deep learning.

---

Torch in recent days also seem to have decent OpenCL support. However it is maintained by a single person. It claims to have full support for all the features of torch. However it does not give an idea about performance. Here is the repository. it is actively maintained.

[cltorch](https://github.com/hughperkins/cltorch)

---

Currently there does not seems to be a decent opencl backend for theano framework but work is in progress. and simple programs can be done with the current version.

---

There are some other opencl frameworks for deeplearning too. It will take some time to sort them out to see if they work properly or not.

Answer (score 10):

An alternative is to use GPU instances on Amazon Web Services.
You can find AMIs with commonly used deep learning packages already installed. For example:

- Torch: https://github.com/torch/torch7/wiki/Cheatsheet#ec2-public-ami
- Theano+Caffe: https://www.kaggle.com/forums/f/208/getting-started/t/11505/an-aws-ami-mainly-for-deep-learning

Tip: use spot instances to get a cheaper price (around 10 cents/hour for a g2.2xlarge).

Comment: This is by far the best solution now! I am currently using this myself because you can install all your software as normal and use their computing power. I think they also do discounts. I'll edit my answer to link to yours as people might not read until it gets more up votes

Answer (score 7):

PlaidML (https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml) is a fully open source deep learning runtime that runs on top of OpenCL and integrates with Keras to provide a familiar user-facing API. The README in the repo has more detailed status, currently convnet inference on Linux is well supported but we (http://vertex.ai) are working to expand completeness and platform support as quickly as we can. Our continuous integration machines include an assortment of AMD and NVIDIA GPUs, all Linux for now but we are also working on adding Mac and Windows.

Comment: Hi @Choong Ng! Is it possible to cross compile `PlaidML` for `armv7-a` platform? And is there any minimum OpenCL version required to use `PlaidML`?

Comment: @Akhilesh Yes, we (Vertex.AI) do test PlaidML on armv7-a platform (Cortex A15), and OpenCL 1.2 is the minimum although I think we have made 1.1 work in the past.

Comment: Thanks to respond. I visited your (vertex.AI) site and PlaidML (https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml), It seems very promising. Actually, mostly deep learning frameworks are required minimum OpenCL 1.2. But I am having OpenCL 1.1 EP. Please can you confirm whether it is possible for cross compile PlaidML for OpenCL 1.1 EP.

Comment: @Akhilesh Thanks, I see your ticket mentioning 1.1 EP and the GC2000 GPU ([link](https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml/issues/137) for those following along). I expect you'll be able to make it work but it may involve small modifications to PlaidML to support EP and any quirks of that chip as well as working with Vivante if you find major bugs in their drivers.

Comment: @ChoongNg, Thanks for the reply. While looking at the below thread, https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml/issues/137 flaub from PlaidML team claimed that they tried on GC2000 Vivante, but failed due to driver issue. Is it still worth we try?

Comment: @ChoongNg, Also in this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plaidml-dev/Kqqexk6OzdM  Alfredo claimed that "The GC2000 will not work, it’s not FP but EP, most kernels won’t compile as EP doesn’t support a lot of the required functionality,".

Answer (score 5):

I'm writing opencl 1.2 support for Tensorflow.  https://github.com/hughperkins/tensorflow-cl  Currently supports:

- blas matrix multiplication
- gradients
- eigen operations such as: reductions, argmin/argmax, per-element operations (binary and unary)

Answer (score 4):

**TensorFlow** now have OpenCL support on the [roadmap](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/resources/roadmap.html).

See: [Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22).

Hopefully not that far away from a working version.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out https://01.org/intel-deep-learning-framework - The Intel® Deep Learning Framework (IDLF) provides a unified framework for Intel® platforms accelerating Deep Convolutional Neural Networks. It is Open Source, so you could port it to AMD hardware as well. The cool thing: it could run on a MacBook Pro with Intel Iris graphics.

Comment: when you say *Intel® platforms* do you mean platforms with Intel® compilers, platforms with Intel® GPUs or do they require both?

Comment: Intel(R) platforms means Intel(R) Processors with or without Intel(R) Processor Graphics and Intel(R) accelerators like Intel(R) Xeon Phi.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [ROCm platform](https://rocm.github.io/), which is driven by AMD. This is the first open-source HPC/Hyperscale-class platform for GPU computing that’s also programming-language independent.

Specifically:

- For deep learning, see https://rocm.github.io/dl.html
- For OpenCL, see:

  - https://rocm.github.io/QuickStartOCL.html
  - https://gpuopen.com/opencl-rocm1-6/
- Useful tutorials can be found here: https://rocm.github.io/tutorials.html