# MAC getting Theano to use the GPU

Tags: cuda, theano

I am having quite a bit of trouble setting up Theano to work with my graphics card on a mac, I really hope you can give me some help.

WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu0 is not available  (error: Unable to get the number of gpus available: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version)

Comment: Are you certain you even have a CUDA compatible GPU in your Mac?

Comment: Searching for the error message yields a number of likely suggestions. e.g. https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/696864/cuda-6-driver-version-is-insufficient-for-cuda-runtime-version/ If you've already searched and exhausted those options, please give more details in your question (you can edit it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an NVIDIA graphics card to use CUDA as CUDA is an NVIDIA product.

To check if your mac has an NVIDIA graphics card:

- Click on the  in the top left of the screen
- About This Mac
- Check the graphics card under Displays...
- If like me you don't see NVIDIA or GeForce anywhere, you can't use CUDA.
- See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30701002/4013571) about alternatives for non NVIDIA for deep learning...

[image: Non Nvidia graphics card]