# Installing Theano on windows with AMD GPU

Tags: python, opencl, theano, keras

After a lot of research and failed attempts I can not get Theano to run on my machine. Im running windows 7 with an AMD Radeon R9. I guess what Im looking for is more of an explanation or clarification. Ive found that without an Nvidia GPU I cant use Cuda and the usual installation method found on Theanos website. So I believe I have to resort to OpenCL? Which isn't supported by Theano. But I have also read about PyCuda and PyOpenCL? Should I try TensorFlow? Is either Python(x,y) or Anaconda better for this environment?

Ultimately I want to run Keras with the Theano backend on either python 2.7 or python 3. I know that this is a lot of questions, I would love any clarification you guys can offer and what is the best method to try and get this thing running.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCL / AMD: Deep Learning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622805/opencl-amd-deep-learning)

Comment: Your best option is to run Theano on the CPU, not on the GPU. OpenCL is just not supported yet.