# How can I use AMD RX Radeon with mxnet package in R specifically

Tags: r, gpu, mxnet, amd-gpu

I read about the possibility to use Nvidia with `mxnet` package, however I didn't find anything about using RX Radeon GPU. can I specifically use RX Radeon with `mxnet` package in R?
[Here](https://mxnet.apache.org/install/windows_setup.html) is the link that explains `mxnet` installation with Nvidia:

> Installing MXNet on a Computer with a GPU Processor
> To install MXNet R package on a computer with a GPU processor, you need the following:
>
> - Microsoft Visual Studio 2013
> - The NVidia CUDA Toolkit
> - The MXNet package
> - CuDNN (to provide a Deep Neural Network library)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCL / AMD: Deep Learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622805/opencl-amd-deep-learning)

Comment: Currently, I am afraid you need a Nvidia card.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have NVidia card at the moment to train on GPU using Apache MXNet out of the box. There were requests to support AMD, but so far it hasn't been implemented yet - https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/621

You could try and use [TVM](https://tvm.ai/) ([Github](https://github.com/dmlc/tvm)). This is a deep learning compiler that can take MXNet model and compile it into intermediate representation, that can be run on multiple platforms.

See this [specific example](https://docs.tvm.ai/tutorials/nnvm/from_mxnet.html) on how to compile an MXNet model